# How to calculate the effective resistance of this circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

How do I calculate the effective resistance of this circuit?
Using only the two formulas:
$$\frac{1}{R_{Total}}
 = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + \cdots$$ and $$R_{Total} = R_1 + R_2 +R_3$$

I know how to calculate current and voltage using the node voltage method and thus derive the resistance. but I'm wondering how do I get the resistance using strictly only the two resistance formula?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t solve that with only those two equations you quoted. You need to convert from [delta to wye](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-resistor-circuits/a/ee-delta-wye-resistor-networks) etc. and reduce the circuit step-by-step before applying those formulas.